# GCP Workflow: serving is disabled for this workflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow

I have error in GCP Workflow which says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "serving is disabled for this workflow",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

Could someone please help to understand how to enable serving?

Comment: have you enable the workflow API? you can follow this documentation on [Create a workflow by using the Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/create-workflow-console)

Comment: @JonB yes, it's enabled.

Comment: as I can see also that your workflow is throwing an error during execution this can be caught follow and see this documentation on [Catch errors](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/catching-errors)